# Ansible: Necessity of running multiple playbooks?

Tags: ansible, dependencies

Owing to needing some dependencies from ansible-galaxy, and other installed software such as ssh-pass, I can't find a way around having to run multiple playbooks sequentially.

Is there a way around this, or is this a feature to be added in future? I've seen it suggested that multiple playbooks may be put in a shell script but surely this is a job for a configuration management program such as ansible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html#ansible-builtin-import-playbook-import-a-playbook) which is merely an import without any other functionality. For example the three playbooks below

```yaml
shell> cat playA.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Play A

shell> cat playB.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Play B

shell> cat playC.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Play C
```

can be put into one playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playABC.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Play A

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Play B

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Play C
```

, or can be imported into one playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playABC-import.yml
- import_playbook: playA.yml
- import_playbook: playB.yml
- import_playbook: playC.yml
```

Both options give the same result. If you need smarter control of the playbooks use [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked when I put installing ssh-pass into a separate playbook. However, I tried to run ansible-galaxy collection install in a separate playbook but this still didn't work.